# i want to protect the contents of table and add the row below the table in word.How to achieve this?

Tags: ms-word

In Microsoft word 2010, I have enabled  Restrict  editing, from review tab.
Question.
i want to protect the contents of table and enable other users add the row below the table.How to achieve this?
By enabling protection,was able to protect the table plus its contents,was not enabled to add row below.

Answer (score 0):

For instert new row- [add a new row to an Word table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662818/add-a-row-to-an-ms-word-table-using-office-interop), I have no idea about how to set Word table as non-editable.