# Add row to word doc using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I created a table in word document using c#, I am trying to add row to the end of the table. for now I have table with 4 rows.

I tried to add like this:

```
  int rowIndex=1;
  this.Tables[1].Rows.Add(this.Tables[1].Rows[rowIndex]);
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-add-rows-and-columns-to-word-tables?view=vs-2017). if I set int `rowIndex=1;` it adds row to the begining of the table, when I tried to set it to `int rowIndex=4;` it adds row to the row before last.

I need a new last row **at the end** of the table, so I tried `int rowIndex=5;`, but then I get :

> Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The requested member of the collection does not exist.
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Rows.get_Item(Int32 Index)

Comment: `var lastRowIndex = this.Tables[i].Rows.Count-1; this.Tables[1].Rows.AddAt(lastRowIndex,this.Tables[1].Rows[rowIndex]);` something like this maybe

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20662891/8024781) answer, it should be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
this.Tables[1].Rows.Add(ref oMissing);
```

Comment: yes, it works thank you:)