# How to Add row in word document table by C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

While adding a new row into word document table I faced a next error:-

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The requested member of
>   the collection does not exist.'

The complete code that I used:-

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object path = string.Format(@"Doc_Path_here");
object readOnly = false;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
doc.Tables[0].Rows.Add();
```

I tried the solutions that existing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662818/add-a-row-to-an-ms-word-table-using-office-interop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516251/add-row-to-word-doc-using-c-sharp) without any positive result.

any help is appreciated.

**Update:-**

The word document has one table, this is confirmed, 
and also the result `nCount` variable of next code is `1`

```
int nCount = doc.Tables.Count;
```

Comment: The error is because `doc.Tables[0].Rows.Add()` on that line specifically. More than likely you don't have any tables; have you confirmed this?

Comment: The problem is that Word ***collections*** are always 1-based. These aren't arrays; Office collections are never 0-based. So use `doc.Tables[1].Rows.Add`

Comment: @CindyMeister, you are right, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described [here in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/Concepts/Miscellaneous/requested-member-of-the-collection-does-not-exist):

> The "requested member of the collection does not exist" error occurs when you try to access an object that does not exist.

You should check the existence of a member before trying to access it. You can use `Count` property of the collection to determine that the member exists.

And as @Cindy Meister mentioned in comments, **Office collections are not Zero based**. Try accessing it like this:

```
doc.Tables[1].Rows.Add();
```